# Is it possible to have a tableless select with multiple rows?

Tags: sql

A `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause gets us a multiple columns without querying a table:

```
SELECT 17+23, REPLACE('bannanna', 'nn', 'n'), RAND(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

How can we write a query that results in multiple rows without referring to a table? Basically, abuse `SELECT` to turn it into a data definition statement. The result could have a single column or multiple columns.

I'm most interested in a DBMS neutral answer, but others (e.g. based on `UNPIVOT`) are welcome. I'd like to collect as many ways of doing this as possible. There's no technique application behind this question; it's more theoretical than practical.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html):

```
SELECT 1
UNION
SELECT 2
```

Looks like this in MySQL:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 | 
| 2 | 
+---+
```

Use `UNION ALL` to avoid the loss of non-unique rows.

Comment: I had hoped to get some more out-there answers before someone dropped the UNION bomb. Ah, well.

Answer (score 21):

You can use [Table Value Constructors](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/) for this if supported by your RDBMS. Here's an example from [Mr Celko](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/)

```
SELECT X.*
FROM   (VALUES (1, 3.07766, 6.31371, 12.7062, 63.65600),
               (2, 1.88562, 2.91999, 4.30265, 9.92482),
               (3, 1.63774, 2.35336, 3.18243, 5.84089)) AS X (A, B, C, D, E);
```

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL's `UNPIVOT` can transpose data from rows to columns. Multiple unpivots is equivalent to the Cartesian product of each unpivoted column.

```
SELECT N, S
  FROM (SELECT 1 aa, 2 ab, 3 ac, 'a' ba, 'b' bb, 'c' bc) s
  UNPIVOT (N for Num in (aa,ab,ac)) AS t
  UNPIVOT (S for Str in (ba,bb,bc)) AS u
```

Result:

> ```
> N | S
> --+--
> 1 | a
> 1 | b
> 1 | c
> 2 | a
> 2 | b
> 2 | c
> 3 | a
> 3 | b
> 3 | c
> ```