# Sql select with custom create table

Tags: sql, sql-server

With SQL, I can select a given value.

```
SELECT (11) ItemID

|------|
|ItemID|
|------|
|  11  |
|------|
```

How could I select 3 values like so:

```
SELECT (11,12,15) ItemID

|------|
|ItemID|
|------|
|  11  |
|  12  |
|  15  |
|------|
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a tableless select with multiple rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886449/is-it-possible-to-have-a-tableless-select-with-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your version of SQL-Server you can also do...

```
SELECT
    yourTable.*
FROM
    (VALUES (11), (12), (15))   AS yourTable(ItemID)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 11 as ItemID
union all
SELECT 12
union all
SELECT 15
```